# failed: Jinja variable 'str object' has no attribute 'get' - For loop - Saltstack

Tags: python, for-loop, yaml, jinja2, salt-stack

I want to set default variables inside a for loop and reuse them inside a sub-for loop.

My state :

```
{% for jboss_application in grains["JBOSS_APP"] %}
   {% if 'app_foobar' in jboss_application %}
      {% import_yaml 'foobar_properties.yml' as jboss_apps %}
   {% endif %}

{% set jboss_app_name = jboss_apps['jboss_defaults']['jboss_app_name'] %} # DEFAULT VARIABLE

{% for jboss_container, jboss_container_values in jboss_apps.iteritems() %}
   {% for key, value in jboss_container_values.items() %}
      {% if value.get('jboss_container_install') == 'True' %} # ERROR

# Do stuff - {{ jboss_app_name.index }}

      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

The foobar_properties.yml file :

```
jboss_defaults:
    jboss_app_name: 'app_foobar'

jboss_container:
    jboss_container_values:
      jboss_container_install: 'True'
      jboss_foobar_variable: 'foobar'
      ...
```

Im getting this error with the 'set' instruction inside my first loop : 
**ERROR : failed: Jinja variable 'str object' has no attribute 'get**'

If I comment or delete the 'set' instruction **my state (and the test) works perfectly**.

FYI : http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/tricks/#accessing-the-parent-loop

I have try many other way to Test if 'jboss_container_install' is 'True' with no success.

Comment: Is that the entire YAML file? If you replace the `{% if %}` with `{{ value }}`, what does it show?

Comment: Hi Ryan, no its just a part of the Yaml file.
You mean {% if {{ value.jboss_container_install }} == 'True' %} ?

Comment: If there are any other keys in `jboss_container` – specifically with string values – they’ll cause problems. And no, I mean delete the `{% if %}` so there’s no error and add `{{ value }}` in front of it. `{% for key, value in jboss_container_values.items() %}{{ value }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: There the error i get with no {% if %} statements
failed: Jinja variable 'str object' has no attribute 'jboss_container_install'

And If i delete the {% set %} statement it works...

Comment: - I have edited my properties file, i have many other string values, but it works without trying to set defaults values